# UIActivityViewController called from button in Custom Cell

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiactivityviewcontroller

In my table view, I have several custom cells.  One is called a button cell as it contains several buttons.  One of them is a share button that I am trying to call a UIActivityViewController.  However, I can not get it to work.  I have subclassed UITableViewCell and called it ButtonCell.  In the header file I have linked up an IBAction called Share.  In the implementation file (ButtonCell.m), I have tried the following.

```
- (IBAction)Share
{

NSString *initialText = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"I like this Catherine Pooler Blog Post: "];
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"iTunesArtwork.png"];

UIActivityViewController *avc = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:@[image, initialText] applicationActivities:nil];
[self presentViewController:avc animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

However, the complier does not like the self.  It does not show up the possibilities of presentViewController:animated:completion.  Is there a way to show a UIActivityViewController from a custom cell with a button.  Thanks for all your help.

EDIT #1
Thanks to Michael and A-live I have figured it out.  Thanks once again for all the help.

In my cellForRowAtIndexPath method I used the following line of code...

```
[buttonCell.shareButton addTarget:self action:@selector(shareTapped) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

By adding the Target I was able to detect taps and call the method shareTapped.  This then bring up the UIActivityViewController and works as I had planned!  Thanks again for all the information and the links.

Comment: `UIView` is supposed to display its own content, while you can get any `UIViewContrtoller` reference and use it to call `presentViewController:...` it is better to let the parent view controller to delegate the cells, it is called a view controller for a good reason. If you can spare some time now to get used to custom delegation, later you'll be able to use this approach easily and naturally, it will serve you well.

Comment: Thanks again @A-Live, there is that word again that I keep stumbling on, "delegate."  Do you have any links to info on custom delegation?  It is something that I need to learn more about!

Comment: You actually need to have a week reference at delegated objects (cell views) and assign delegating object (view controller)  whenever you create a cell. Check this section [Implementing a Delegate for a Custom Class](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/general/conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/DelegatesandDataSources/DelegatesandDataSources.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010810-CH11-SW29) and read the full article. Other helpful tutorials [(like this one)](http://ios-objectivec-tutorials.blogspot.com/2012/10/delegates-in-objective-c.html) will be helpful to start using the protocols.

Comment: @A-Live, Thanks again, I have edited my answer and was wondering what you thought about it.

Comment: That's OK, don't forget to get rid of `share` method at `ButtonCell.m`  not to be confused in the future. Also be careful with reused cells: if you want the button to have different target/action at different cells, you'll want to use `removeTarget:action:forControlEvents:` (check `UIControl` documentation for details) before `addTarger...`.

Comment: @A-Live, Thanks.  The button only appears on one type of cell.  So reuse shouldn't be a problem. And I will make sure to ditch the share method. Thanks for all the help and links.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

UITableViewCell descends from UIView and not UIViewController, which is why "`presentViewController:animated:completion:`" is not an option for you from your subclassed table view cell.

If you want to present your Activity View Controller, you need to (somehow) get a reference to the view controller that your cell (which is in a table, which is in a content view, etc.) is sitting within.

And *then* with that view controller reference (which I'm naming "`myViewController`"), you can call "`[myViewController presentViewController: avc animated: YES completion: nil];`"

P.S. one more thing: for Objective-C, best practice is that variable and method names should start with lower case letters (use "`share`" and not "`Share`").

Comment: First off, thanks for the fast response, and the tip on "share" not "Share"!  Could you give me any hints as to getting a reference to the view controller the cell is in?  The cell itself is in a UITableViewController named BlogDetailViewController.  I can't import that in as ButtonCell is imported into BlogDetailViewController.  Thanks again for your help.

Comment: I kinda figured you were going to ask me how to get a reference to the parent controller. There's a few ways to pass this along: 1) in your ButtonCell, you can add a (weak) parentViewController property and set it when you reference the ButtonCell object in your itemAtIndexPath method 2) you can use NSNotification to tell the parent view controller to present the activity view controller 3) if the table uses your BlogDetailViewController as a data source or delegate, that's how you can get a reference to it

Comment: Thanks so much for the great information.  I am going to look into #1 and #3, as I have never used NSNotifications yet.  But I am sure with all this to go on, I'll get there!  Thanks again, let you know how the progress goes.

Comment: Thanks for all the help, please se my edit and let me know what you think.